# How to pass multiple child arrays broken down from a larger parent array to a method call in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

How to pass multiple child arrays broken down from a larger parent array to a method call in Groovy?

Due to size limits I need to break down a large number of items in an array into smaller arrays, than pass those smaller arrays to
a method call.

For example,

```
def childIds = [100001, 100002, , 100003, 100004, 100005, 100006, 100007, 100008, 100009, 100010]

//break down childIds to chunks of 3 
def subChildren = childIds.collate(3) 

//Pass these smaller chunks to the method

/*Pass the first 3 childIds from the smaller arrays to the getWorkProperties method 
until all 10 have been processed.*/
//i.e [[100001, 100002, 100003], [100004, 100005, 100006], [100007, 100008, 100009], [100010]]
def getWorkProperties = getListedWorkitems(collection, project, subChildren)
return getWorkProperites
```

Comment: Do you mean like this `subChildren.each{ batch-> getListedWorkitems(collection, project, batch) }`

Comment: That's right, for this particular situation I can't pass more than 10 records at once.  I need to break down the larger array into smaller arrays (no more than of 3 per array) then pass them in chunks until all 10 records have been processed.  Does that make sense?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`collate` you already have identified as the tool to chunk your input
(yet, you might be better off if you could turn your input into an
iterator or stream).  Then to stich back together things you could use
`collectMany`.

e.g.

```
def childIds = [100001, 100002, 100003, 100004, 100005, 100006, 100007, 100008, 100009, 100010]

println(
childIds.collate(3).collectMany{
    it.findAll{ (it & 1) == 1 }
}
)
// → [100001, 100003, 100005, 100007, 100009]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this.  By turning the input into an iterator or stream do you mean to skip the collate(chunking process) and process x number of records in the array until all 10 are processed?  How would that look?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help here.  I was able to solve the issue using the following code:

```
def childIds = [10000, 100001, 100002, , 100003, 100004, 100005, 100006, 100007, 100008, 100009, 100010]

def children = []
def countrecords = childIds.size()
//if more than 10 records batch the workItems passed to the method in increments of 10
if (countrecords > 10) {
    //break down to 10 total records
    def subChildren = childIds.collate(10)
    subChildren.each{ batch-> 
        def batchChildren = getListedWorkitems(collection, project, batch)
        //add individual ids to the children array
        batchChildren.each{ wi -> children.add(wi)}
        
    }
} else {

     children = getListedWorkitems(collection, project, childIds)
}
//return the children
return children
```